# How can I set up multiple local notifications on my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to set up multiple Local Notifications, like the one shown on this code, on my AppDelegate.  Is this possible?

Also, I have set up this notification shown on the code below, but how can I make repeat from Monday to Friday?

Here's my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */

NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent setWeekday:5];
[dateComponent setHour:11];
[dateComponent setMinute:26];


UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd setDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];



UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"Let the Music Play"];
[notification setFireDate:dd.date];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the repeatInterval property of the notification to NSWeekdayCalendarUnit.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I set it up for it to be from Monday to Friday? I don't want it to show up during Saturday or Sunday. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the way I set it up: `UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"Let the Music Play"];
    [notification setFireDate:dd.date];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];` Since there are various **Notifications**, I added them in the end like this: `[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notification, notification1, notification2, notification3, notification4, notification5, nil]];` Sometimes it doesn't fire. Why?